# Percentage chance of selected numbers JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

I am creating a spinning wheel of luck. So I have numbers 1 to 6.
Here is some code:

First I get a random number between 0 and 7, so (1,2,3,4,5,6)

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
```

What I want to do is to set percentage like this:

```
var goldChance = 10;
var blueChance = 40;
var grayChance = 50;
```

`goldChance` are numbers `2` and `5`,

`blueChance` are numbers `6` and `3`, and

`graychance` are numbers `4` and `1`.

So when the wheel starts to spin it should show numbers `4` and `1` for `50%` of the spin, numbers `6` and `3` for `40%` and only rare numbers `2` and `5` should show `10%` of the time. That way if you are lucky you will get that gold numbers.

Is there any way to set Math.random() to includes chances?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"...for 50% of the spin..."* 50% of the *spin*? Or 50% of the times you spin?

Comment: why not get a random (`Math.random(array_length)`) number from an *array* `[1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6, 2, 5]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't get a random number 1 <= n <= 6, instead get a random number 0 <= n <= 19 and pick from an array of twenty entries with your distribution of numbers in it:

```
const numbers = [2, 5, 6, 3, 6, 3, 6, 3, 6, 3, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1];
const result = numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)];
```

Example:

```js
const numbers = [2, 5, 6, 3, 6, 3, 6, 3, 6, 3, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1];
const tbody = document.getElementById("results");
const rows = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].map(number => {
  const row = document.createElement("tr");
  row.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",
    `<td>${number}</td><td>0</td><td>0%</td>`);
  tbody.appendChild(row);
  return row;
});
let draws = 0;
let timer = 0;
doDraw();

function doDraw() {
  const number = numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)];
  ++draws;
  const row = rows[number - 1];
  const countCell = row.cells[1];
  countCell.textContent = Number(countCell.textContent) + 1;
  rows.forEach(row => {
    row.cells[2].textContent = (Number(row.cells[1].textContent) / draws * 100).toFixed(2) + "%";
  });
  timer = setTimeout(doDraw, 1);
}

document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("click", function() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = 0;
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
td {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
The percentages approach the gold (5% each for 2 and 5 [total of 10%]), blue (20% each for 3 and 6 [total of 40%]), and grey (25% each for 1 and 4 [total of 50%]) levels over time as the randomness works itself out...
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Occurrences</th>
      <th>%</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="results"></tbody>
</table>
<input id="stop" value="Stop" type="button">
```

Comment: Yes, exactly what I wanted. Thanks! But is there any better way of structuring the numbers so I don't have long array [1,2,1,2...] but let's say `var gold = 10`, `var blue = 40` ...

Comment: @petar11199 - 20 entries isn't that long. :-) We could fairly easy produce the array with a more concise starting point such as `var levels = {gold: {values: [2, 5], percent: 10}, blue: {values: [3, 6], percent: 40}, gray: {values: [1, 4], percent: 50}};` but it seems like it makes things more complicated rather than less...

Comment: Yes, I agree. Thanks again T.J. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array with probabilities and check and count against a random value.

This function sets first the return value to the last possible index and iterates until the rest of the random value is smaller than the actual probability.

The probabilities have to sum to one.

```js
function getRandomIndexByProbability(probabilities) {
    var r = Math.random(),
        index = probabilities.length - 1;

    probabilities.some(function (probability, i) {
        if (r < probability) {
            index = i;
            return true;
        }
        r -= probability;
    });
    return index;
}

var i,
    probabilities = [0.25, 0.05, 0.2, 0.25, 0.05, 0.2],
    count = {},
    index;

probabilities.forEach(function (_, i) { count[i + 1] = 0; });

for (i = 0; i < 1e6; i++) {
    index = getRandomIndexByProbability(probabilities);
    count[index + 1]++;
}

console.log(count);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar problem for a coding challenge by generating a number 1 <= n <= 100, and then assigning portions of that range to represent the probability desired.

So, for example, to get 1 ~50% of the time, 2 10% of the time, etc.:

```
if (n > 0 && n <= 50) {
  return 1;
} else if (n > 50 && n <= 60) {
  return 2;
} else if ...
```